# sudoku validator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, validation, sudoku

I tried converting python file to ruby for sudoku validator. can someone help me to complete?

```
class Sudoku
  def isinRange(board)
    @N = 9
    for i in (0..@N)
      for j in (0..@N)
        if ((board[i][j] <= 0) or (board[i][j] > 9))
          raise False 
        end
      end

      raise True
    end 
  end

  def isValidSudoku(board)
    @N = 9
    if (isinRange(board) == False)
```

............

```
if __FILE__ == $0
    board = [ [ 7, 9, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 8, 6 ],
    [ 6, 4, 3, 8, 2, 7, 1, 5, 9 ],
    [ 8, 5, 1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 2, 4 ],
    [ 2, 6, 5, 9, 7, 3, 8, 4, 1 ],
    [ 4, 8, 9, 5, 6, 1, 2, 7, 3 ],
    [ 3, 1, 7, 4, 8, 2, 9, 6, 5 ],
    [ 1, 3, 6, 7, 4, 8, 5, 9, 2 ],
    [ 9, 7, 4, 2, 1, 5, 6, 3, 8 ],
    [ 5, 2, 8, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7 ] ]
    if (isValidSudoku(board))
      puts "valid"
    else 
      puts "Not valid"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: _"help me to complete"_ – what’s missing? Or is it just turning this into valid Ruby?

Comment: Very little of this is idiomatic Ruby, and this isn't a program rewriting service. You need to break your problem down into smaller functions that can be tested separately. For example, a typical sudoku box equals `!9`, but validating or solving an entire puzzle is something you're better off using a search engine to find an algorithm for unless you really want to roll your own in a language you don't really understand.

Comment: I will also point out that your board representation is non-standard and potentially ambiguous from a validation perspective. A 9x9 sudoku is a grid with boxes, columns, and rows, and a number of common representations already exist such as the 81 digit string or rcrn already exist. You might also want to Google Crook's algorithm if validating boxes, rows, and columns separately doesn't suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
require 'matrix'

class Sodoku
  RANGE = (1..9).to_a

  def initialize(board)
    @board = board
  end

  def valid?
    matrix.square? &&
      subset_valid?(rows) && subset_valid?(columns) && subset_valid?(boxes)    
  end

  private 

  attr_reader :board

  def rows
    board
  end

  def columns
    board.transpose
  end

  def boxes
    RANGE.map(&method(:submatrix))
  end

  def subset_valid?(lists)
    lists.all? { |list| list.sort == RANGE }
  end

  def matrix
    Matrix[*board]
  end

  def submatrix(number)
    n = RANGE.max / 3

    ranges = number.pred.divmod(n).map { |x| (x * n..x.succ * n - 1) }
    
    matrix.minor(*ranges)
  end
end

board = [ [ 7, 9, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 8, 6 ], [ 6, 4, 3, 8, 2, 7, 1, 5, 9 ], [ 8, 5, 1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 2, 4 ], [ 2, 6, 5, 9, 7, 3, 8, 4, 1 ], [ 4, 8, 9, 5, 6, 1, 2, 7, 3 ], [ 3, 1, 7, 4, 8, 2, 9, 6, 5 ], [ 1, 3, 6, 7, 4, 8, 5, 9, 2 ], [ 9, 7, 4, 2, 1, 5, 6, 3, 8 ], [ 5, 2, 8, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7 ] ]
invalid = [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] ]

Sodoku.new(board).valid?
#=> true

Sodoku.new(invalid).valid?
#=> false
```

Comment: Sudoku Validation
I need this in ruby
Write a sudoku validator. This function should return true if the 2-D array represents valid sudoku and false otherwise. To be valid sudoku:
1. Each row must have the digits from 1 to 9 exactly once.
2. Each column must have the digits from 1 to 9 exactly once.
3. Each 3x3 box must have the digits from 1 to 9 exactly once.

Comment: @monishravindra I updated my answer to fix the missing 3x3 box validation.